# CasperJS click event having AJAX call

Tags: ajax, screen-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to fetch data from a site by simulating events using CasperJS with phantomJS 1.7.0.

I am able to simulate normal click events and select events. But my code fails in following scenario:

When I click on button / anchor etc on remote page, the click on remote page  initiates an AJAX call / JS call(depending on how that page is implemented by programmer.).

In case of JS call, my code works and I get changed data. But for clicks where is AJAX call is initiated, I do not get updated data.

For debugging, I tried to get the page source of the element container(before and after), but I see no change in code.

I tried to set wait time from 10 sec to 1 ms range, but that to does not reflect any changes in behavior.

Below is my piece of code for clicking. I am using an array of CSS Paths, which represents which element(s) to click.

```
/*Click on array of clickable elements using CSS Paths.*/
fn_click = function(){
casper.each(G_TAGS,function(casper, cssPath, count1) 
                    {
                            casper.then ( function() {
                            casper.click(cssPath);

                            this.echo('DEBUG AFTER CLICKING -START HTML ');
                            //this.echo(this.getHTML("CONTAINER WHERE DETAILS CHANGE"));
                            this.echo('DEBUG AFTER CLICKING -START HTML');
                            casper.wait(5000, function() 
                                                    {   

                                                        casper.then(fn_getData);
                                                    } 
                                    );
                            });     
                    });
};
```

UPDATE:

I tried to use remote-debug option from phantomJS, to debug above script. 
It is not working. I am on windows. I will try to run remote debugging on Ubuntu as well.

Please help me. I would appreciate any help on this.

UPDATE:

Please have a look at following code as a sample.

```
https://gist.github.com/4441570
```

Content before click and after click are same.

I am clicking on sorting options provided under tag (votes / activity etc.).

Comment: Is there any update to this? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Go to GitHub link. All I could figure out was there was some error due to jQuery injection. I have posted my comments and questions there and I am still waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today. I found this post, which put me in the direction of jQuery.

After some testing I found out that there was already a jQuery loaded on that webpage. (A pretty old version though)

Loading another jQuery on top of that broke any js calls made, so also the link that does an Ajax call.

To solve this I found http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

and I added the following to my code:

```
    this.evaluate(function () { jq = $.noConflict(true) } );
```

Anything that was formerly assigned to $ will be restored that way. And the jQuery that you injected is now available under 'jq'.

Hope this helps you guys.

Comment: Don't want to get my hopes up prematurely, but this fix seems to be working.  Strange since I can find jQuery on the page that Im scraping..  Anyway. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have to be jQuery. $ might reference another library and will get broken when you inject jQuery. Using noConflict() will restore the previous alias.