# jQuery not working, but document.querySelector does (CasperJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

The website displays the visitor's IP address in an `h1` tag with `id = "ip"`

When I use `return document.querySelector('#ip').innerText;` it displays the correct IP address and everything is well.

However, when I use `return $('#ip').text();` it displays `null`

Any ideas why?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("http://mikeyaworski.com/IP", function() {

    var ip = this.evaluate(function() {
        // return document.querySelector('#ip').innerText; // does work
        return $('#ip').text(); // doesn't work, but it should
    });

    this.echo("\nYour public IP address is: " + ip);
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Are you sure `$` is `jQuery`? Maybe you have some other library loaded and it's conflicting.

Comment: @Barmar What I've posted is my entire code and I've not done anything with any libraries (as far as I'm aware). I'm following the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860928/how-do-i-use-jquery-in-casperjs).

Comment: Still, that doesn't mean `$` is jQuery. What does `console.log($.fn.jquery)` tell you?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: @Barmar: Logging that inside the `evaluate` function does nothing. Logging that outside of the `evaluate` function gives `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` which is what I'd expect. And no, I guess I haven't loaded jQuery. However, in another [project I've done](http://code.mikeyaworski.com/CasperJS/twitter), I didn't "load jQuery" (I think) and it ended up working.

Comment: I don't know CasperJS. But see: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs

Comment: @Barmar Oh, well thanks for the effort. Yeah I've read that documentation before and it seemed to work without it (before). I'll try it again anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading jQuery from [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js) to a place on my computer.

Then I followed the [documentation](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-jquery-with-casperjs) on this topic and it seemed to work (oddly, because in the past, I haven't needed to follow these "rules").

My code ended up like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("http://mikeyaworski.com/IP", function() {

    // this is the changed part
    casper.page.injectJs('path/to/jquery-1.11.0.js');

    var ip = this.evaluate(function() {
        // return document.querySelector('#ip').innerText;
        return $('#ip').text();
    });

    this.echo("\nYour public IP address is: " + ip);
});

casper.run();
```

---

This worked as well:

```
// this is the changed part
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["path/to/jquery-1.11.0.js"]
});

casper.start("http://mikeyaworski.com/IP", function() {

    var ip = this.evaluate(function() {
        // return document.querySelector('#ip').innerText;
        return $('#ip').text();
    });

    this.echo("\nYour public IP address is: " + ip);
});

casper.run();
```

---

**However**, what I still find odd is that on [this other script](http://code.mikeyaworski.com/CasperJS/twitter), I used jQuery just fine without injecting it anywhere, or even having it downloaded on my computer. I'd like some more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, early versions of jQuery on a page may collide with the version of jQuery you are using in the test. If you upgrade your version, the two jQuerys dont collide. This is related to this other thread:

[CasperJS click event having AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098483/casperjs-click-event-having-ajax-call)

There are other ways to fix it without changing your version of jQuery.